# DownThemAll alternative for Firefox Quantum?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, download-manager

previously i was using **DownThemAll** extension on my Firefox.
recently i upgraded my firefox to Quantum

since DownthemAll does not support latest Firefox do we have any alternative for DownThemAll extension.

[source](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) of extension !

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a different web browser that can install Firefox extensions, like ***Waterfox***; here a videotutorial: https://youtu.be/OQ--UyyWbx8